# upload audio recording to ftp

Tags: ios, file-upload, ftp, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I need to upload audio files recorded from my application .I am unable to upload aac files to ftp.
Here is my code to upload

```cs
FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(myftppath);

                ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username,password);

                ftp.UseBinary = true;
                ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(audioFilePath);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                fs.Close();

                Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
                ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                ftpstream.Close();
                ftpstream.Flush();
```

**The code works for uploading other files like txt,png,mp3 etc but not for aac files.**
Please help

Comment: What doesn't work?  Do you get an error or exception?  Where does it fail?  What do the server logs say?  How large is the failed file compared to the files that work?

Comment: @Jason No errors or exception .ftpwebresponse status code is "closing control" and status description is "221 Good Bye".Files are of same size as that of the successfully uploaded file.

Comment: can you provide full code for FTP uploading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct. You may try this,

1. If you are running the app on simulator,check if your OS has permission to write file to ftp.
2. Install your app on real device and try to upload using the same code.

If none works then find out the exact cause of error using try block.